# Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

While trying to login with Facebook, I am facing this error:

> Graph returned an error: This authorization code has been used.

Please suggest me what to do? I have placed all my app_id and app_secret correctly in code.

```
config.php
if (!session_id()) {
    session_start();
}
require_once('Facebook/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'XXXXXXXX', // Replace {app-id} with your app id
  'app_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
  ]);
  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

callback.php

```
require_once("config.php");
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
if(isset($_GET['state']))
{
    $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
}
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
if (!$accessToken) {
    header("Location: ".$siteurl."login.php");
    exit;
  }
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
    $response = $fb->get("/me?fields=id,email", $accessToken);
    $userData = $response->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    $_SESSION['userData'] = $userData;
    $_SESSION['accessToken'] = (string) $accessToken;
    header("Location: ".$siteurl."profile.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks for correcting me I am new here.Will we help me with my erroe

Comment: Looks like you are calling the `getRedirectLoginHelper` method twice. And your handling of the state parameter seems completely wrong - that should be _in_ your session already when you get redirected back from Facebook to your app, you appear to be _writing_ it into the session at that point, which completely defeats its purpose.

Comment: I removed getRedirectLoginHelper from callback.php file. Still Its showing same error. If I didn't handled that state condition it gives me **Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.** error

Comment: Looks like you are not handling your session correctly here to begin with. Wrapping session_start into `if (!session_id())` makes little sense - remove that if, and just start the session.

Comment: I removed sessions if condition stil its showing me same error.

Comment: Then something must be going wrong with your sessions in the first place. The SDK puts the state value into the session itself. so that it can compare that value to the GET parameter that gets passed when Facebook redirects back to your app. Putting it into the session again yourself at this point defeats its main purpose (protection against CSRF-style attacks.)

Comment: if i didn't handle that state condition it gives me 'Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.' this error. Thwn why its showing me this error?

Comment: Because you session is not working properly … As I explained just then, the SDK generates a random state value and puts it into the session, the moment you call the `getLoginUrl` method. If that _had_ worked properly, it would find that value in the session when it comes to the point where it tries to exchange the code for a token. The error message _“Required param "state" missing from persistent data.”_ means it _didn’t_ work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Now I used this from Facebook developer site.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();  
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }
  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{app-id}',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : '{api-version}'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id) {                      // Load the SDK asynchronously
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>
//  The JS SDK Login Button 
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
<div id="status">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to redirect my page. How should I redirect my page after login?